# Can you say "The inequality B encompasses A"?

Tags: terminology, article-writing

I know this is a silly question for English speakers, but as a non-native speaker, please help me communicate in math.

I am about to report in a formal academic paper on inequality B, which is a generalization of the traditional well known inequality A.

For example,
$$x \leq 0 \quad\text{  (a sample of the inequality A)},$$
$$x \leq f(z) \quad\text{(a sample of the inequality B)},$$
where $f(z)$ takes a negative value. The inequality A immediately follow from B because we assume $f(z) \leq 0$. In other words, B coincides with A only in the special case where $f(z) = 0$.

In Japanese, we use the expression "(generalized) inequality B contains inequality A" very often, because once you have the generalized inequality, you can derive inequalities for special cases. This phrase is so common that everyone can immediately understand the situation like the above example. So, this is convenient phrase.

Is this kind of convenient phrase allowed in English? In other words, can you say "The inequality B encompasses A?"

If so, what kind of words (cotain, include, encompass, ...) should be used?

If not, what is the best way to express the relationship between inequalities A and B, using inequality B as the subject?

I have searched on Google scholar with the query "inequality encompasses". However, it could not resolve my question.

Comment: I suspect the term you're looking for is "implies". The inequality $x \leq f(z)$ implies the inequality $x \leq 0$. The term "implies" is a very general term. Whenever one proposition $P$ follows logically from another proposition $Q$, we say that "$Q$ implies $P$".

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, however, I believe the most common thing to say would be "If $f(z)<0$, then inequality B implies inequality A"

Comment: Do you have $A$ and $B$ the wrong way round in the title of your question?  Depending on the exact context, we would probably say "implies" or "strengthens", if $B$ gives more information than $B$ in a given situation, or "generalises", if $B$ applies in a wider range of situations than $A$ and implies $A$ in situations where both are applicable.

Comment: I have not seen "Inequality B encompasses A". I would avoid that. Say, "Inequality B implies Inequality A".

Comment: Too late to edit, but the third $B$ in my comment should read $A$.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this inequality is the main result of your paper, then you'll want to use special language to emphasize things, like "we improve upon [inequality A] with the tighter bound $f(x)$". Or "we show a stronger result, $x\le f(z)$, etc. If this is a minor point, then something like "note that this implies the well-known [inequality A]" is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. Yes. A is my main result. Can you say "The inequality A provides a stronger bound than the inequality B"?

Comment: @Light Yagmi, The result *provides* a stronger bound. But inequality A *is* a stronger bound.

Comment: thank you so much. Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

If whenever inequality A is true inequality B is also true then I would say "inequality A **implies** inequality B".

Comment: @AdamRubinson:  What you say agrees with the example given in the Question, but user247327's Answer is internally consistent. $A\implies B$ means that "whenever $A$ is true, $B$ is true".